# Is there a VSCode extension to go from GraphQL schema to the Golang resolver?

Tags: visual-studio-code, go, graphql

We have a query or mutation definition and the resolver code for it in Go file. Of course they have identical names, but we can have several functions with this name in Go. That is why, I am asking can we go from definition in `.graphql` file to the resolver code in `.go` file? Using some VSCode extension or internal VSCode tool.

I have tried **Go to Definition (F12)** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> functions in VSCode, it doesn't work. Also the **GraphQL: Language Feature Support** extension doesn't allow us to go to the query/mutation implementation.

Comment: I honestly doubt. It'd need to be coded for Golang specifically, but searching "graphql golang" yields no promising results.